# XY axis to multiple subfigures

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I am including 3 subfigures for which i want a common X (Time) and Y (Amplitude) axis labels. Note labels should be above subcaption handler i.e., (a) (b) and (c)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx,amsmath,subfigure,adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
 \subfigure[]{\adjincludegraphics[trim={0 0 0 0}, clip,scale=.4]{1.eps}}
 \subfigure[]{\adjincludegraphics[trim={0 0 0 0}, clip,scale=.4]{2.eps}}
 \subfigure[]{\adjincludegraphics[trim={0 0 0 0}, clip,scale=.4]{3.eps}}
 \caption{(a) Original, (b) and (c) estimated.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are many different definitions of \subfigure, so a complete MWE would be useful.

Comment: I found that for complex graphing nothing beats `pgfplots` see (http://pgfplots.net)